# � symbols in whole website from MySQL retrieved database data

Tags: php, html

So I don't know why but when I put my website up online from offline suddenly the website will not show any symbols and I'm not sure why. It worked fine offline. Really couldn't find any info on this never seen it before :(

[image]
My header.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo <<<_END

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
_END;
```

and index.php

```
<?php
$title = 'Baz Building';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'nav.php';
?>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to baz Build by Richard Hayward</h1><br><br>
    <div class="col-8">
        <h2 class="text-center">Houses</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
        <?php
        //Get connection details from file
        require_once'mysqli-con.php';
        //Create new connection
        $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db); //Create new object, MYSQLI connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error); //Display error if failed to connect


         // Create first query to get all house names for count
        $query_names = $conn->query('SELECT name FROM house_names'); // Query all names data
        $num_rows = $query_names->num_rows; // Get the number of rows for loop

        //Start loop for output of each item
        for($c = 0 ; $c < $num_rows ; ++$c){

            //Query Join
            $query_names->data_seek($c);
        $name = $query_names->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

            $query = "SELECT house_names.id, house_names.name, houses_has_features.house_names_id, house_types.type, features.feature FROM house_names
JOIN houses_has_features
ON house_names.id = houses_has_features.house_names_id
JOIN house_types
ON house_types.id = houses_has_features.house_types_id
JOIN features
ON houses_has_features.features_id = features.id
WHERE house_names.name = \"$name[0]\"";


            $query_join = $conn->query($query);

        $rows = $query_join->num_rows;

        echo '<p>';

            //Output name and type for each item
        $first_rows = $query_join->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo '<li class="list-group-item active">' . $first_rows['name'] . '</li>';
        echo '<li class="list-group-item"><b>Type: </b>' . $first_rows['type'] . '</li>';
        echo '<li class="list-group-item"><b>Features: </b>';
        for($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) //Features loop
        {
            $query_join->data_seek($j);
            $row = $query_join->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

            //Output all features for each item
        echo $row[4] . ', ';
        };
        };


        // Close objects
        $conn->close();
        $query_join->close();
        $query_names->close();


        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably have non-UTF8 character in your database. Perhaps you database has the wrong encoding.

Comment: oooh maybe the DB. I set the page to UTF8

Comment: Server connection collation Documentation: UTF8_general_ci

Answer (score 2):

This is an article on unicode that's worth reading : [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

> The Single Most Important Fact About Encodings
>
> If you completely forget everything I just explained, please remember
>   one extremely important fact. It does not make sense to have a string
>   without knowing what encoding it uses. You can no longer stick your
>   head in the sand and pretend that "plain" text is ASCII.
>
> There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.

Comment: Ok thanks guys I couldn't find any data on this but it seems there is plenty I really just needed to be at least pointed in the right direction as I have no idea where this was coming from thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

check the relative path and the URL is with WWW ot without www

Comment: without but I tried with www and doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after reading that post (thanks for the link), I switched the database to utf8mb4_bin and took out the entries with symbols and put them back in again found that the symbols are now showing :)

I also added to my header

thanks for all the help guys :)